# Constantes globales en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, constantes

¿Existe alguna manera de compartir constantes / variables en una misma BBDD entre varios procedimientos almacendas en SQL SERVER?

No quiero usar tablas temporales, ni funciones, ni procedimientos almacenados.

He visto que se puede hacer alguna cosa con el Context, pero la idea es poder compartir constantes entre procedimientos, definidas una unica vez.

Comment: a qué te refieres con "compartir" variables?, entre sesiones?, usuarios?, instancias?, bases de datos?, servidores?

Comment: En una misma base de datos, definir constantes en un solo lugar y poder usarlas en varios procedimientos. Edito para que quede mas claro

Comment: lamentablemente aún no entiendo bien lo que preguntas, pero no hay "constantes globales definidas por el usuario" en SQL Server

Comment: Pero a nivel base de datos o en tu solución, en tu solución puedes tener el Context y pasarselo a todos para no realizar a cada rato la instancia de tu base, pero no se si es eso a lo que te refieres

Comment: Para definir valores en una misma base de datos que puedan ser utilizados desde cualquier parte del código, tienes que guardarlos en una tabla. Context solo está disponible dentro de cada sesión. Creo que estamos ante un [problema xy](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%c3%a9-es-el-problema-xy)

Comment: No lo creo @LuisCazares mi problema lo tengo claro, aunque quizas, mas que un problema, sea una duda, porque no me bloquea el desarrollo. Dentro de mi BBDD, quiero definir constantes, para poder usarlas en ciertas comprobaciones de procedimientos almacenados. He estado informandome y no veo que sea posible. Solo era por ver si me alumbrabais el camino, o ciertamente, SQL tiene esta limitación, hay que morir a tablas temporales y no se si eso, me llega a interesar.

Comment: No me refería a tablas temporales sino a tablas permanentes. Similar a como SQL Server usa de forma interna sys.configurations.

Comment: Diego revisa [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-configurations-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) o [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-configuration-options-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) o bien [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para ver si eso satisface tus requerimientos. Si no es nada de eso, entonces pulsa en [edit]  y explica con mayor claridad el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve investigando y la manera que vi a día de hoy para poder generar "constantes", dado que como tal no existen, es **generar una tabla, de solo lectura**, en la que consultarlas.